Android Compose: How to hide soft keyboard when a Textfield is in focus?
I have a screen with a TextField and a custom keyboard. I would like the soft keyboard not to show up at all, even when user clicks on the TextField.
I tried using keyboardController?.hide() and also focusManager.clearFocus(), but both of them didn't help.
I even tried inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.currentFocus?.windowToken, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
package com.example.customkeyboard

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.ClipboardManager
import android.content.Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE
import android.content.Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.compose.foundation.ExperimentalFoundationApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.combinedClickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalFocusManager
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalSoftwareKeyboardController
import com.example.customkeyboard.ui.theme.CustomKeyboardTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            CustomKeyboardTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    Greeting(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun Greeting(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val text = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val activity = context as Activity
    val inputMethodManager =
        context.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    Column (
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ){

        TextField(
            value = text.value,
            onValueChange = { text.value = it },
            modifier = Modifier
                .combinedClickable(
                    onClick = {
                        keyboardController?.hide()
                        focusManager.clearFocus()
                        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                            activity.currentFocus?.windowToken, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS
                        )
                    },
                    onLongClick = {
                        val clipboard: ClipboardManager =
                            context.getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
                        text.value = clipboard.primaryClip?.getItemAt(0)?.text.toString()
                        keyboardController?.hide()
                    }
                ),
        )

        val keys = arrayOf("Q","W","E","R")
        Row {
            keys.forEach {
                Button(onClick = {
                    text.value += it
                }) {
                    Text(text = it, color = Color.Black)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-can-i-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard-programmatically?rq=2

@sureshmadaparthi, I have tried the suggestions (as stated in the Question), none of them work. Is there something I missed?

@Saral Please edit your post and include the code that you tried. keyboardController should usually work. The other question is why you need to use a TextField if the user should not be able to enter anything into it?

@BenjyTec As mentioned in the Question, there is a custom keyboard, through which user will be entering text. That's the reason, I want the standard keyboard to be always hidden.
